# Side view of an object

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I got homework to do but I'm struggling with it.

So, what I got is top and front view which are the same like in the picture below. What I need is side view of that object, and also I need to draw an object himself (but I don't know what that object looks like because it's not given, only what I got is front and top view, and when I find side view I will know how that object looks like).

Hope you understand. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Crop the photo, man. Crop the photo. Only 30% of it is information.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47982/side-view-missing ... you were supposed to improve that question, not post another

Answer (score -2):

This is an ambiguously defined problem. The solution is a square or any cylindrical object with equal x and z extension. Note that it has to have 3 layers in y direction (otherwise there would be no solid lines on the top and front views.

The simplest ones are the cilinder sliced between two square prisms or the other way round.

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer, please explain.

Comment: Perhaps because answering a duplicate may not be appreciated. Or the answer is too broad.